# What are Trash and .Trash-1000?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, delete, trash

When deleting a file a `.Trash-1000` folder is created which contains two subfolders `files` and `info`.

My deleted file as well as folder is saved all inside the subfolder `files`.

If I Select Trash and Right click + Properties I cannot see the location of trash, just the details of files it contains.

If all my deleted files are saved in a hidden folder in same directory, what is Trash? Is it just a virtual folder which seems to exist but really doesn't?

Comment: Did you delete the file on a USB drive?

Comment: @StefanHamcke are you asking how to delete a file on USB drive?

Comment: No, I just wanted to ask whether you deleted the file on a USB drive or in your home folder. If I delete a file in my home folder, it is moved to *~/.local/share/Trash/files*, but if I delete it on a USB drive, it has the effect you describe in your question, except that in *Properties* the location says something like */media/stefan/b5b259dc-048e-4a89-82c1-d4356c6ee663*.

Answer (score 4):

GNOMEish file managers need a place to put trashed files.

- Deleted files on your "home" partition go to:  `/home/username/.local/share/Trash`
- Deleted files on other partitions can't be copied there for performance and space reasons.

So it tries to put them in the /.Trash-$UID folder of the file's partition.  Without rw access to that folder, no trash.

Run this bash in the partition root as the user who needs a trash.

```
sudo mkdir .Trash-$UID && sudo chown $USER:$USER .Trash-$UID
```

You can delete this folder and disable write access to the / to disable that feature.